# How to remove duplicate entries from a list of list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I am having a list of list like below,

```
List<List<String>> ListsToMerge
```

Let's say this list is having 3 more inner list.

```
ListsToMerge [0] = {"Apple", "Grapes", "Banana"}
ListsToMerge [1] = {"Guava", "Apple", "Strawberry"}
ListsToMerge [2] = {"Strawberry", "Almonds", "Peach"}
```

I need to remove the duplicate entries from the above list and create a main list.

```
List<string> MergedList
```

This MergedList should remove the duplicate entries and only should contain

```
MergedList = {"Apple","Grapes","Banana","Guava","Strawberry","Almonds","Peach"}
```

Comment: `var MergedList = ListsToMerge.SelectMany(z => z).Distinct();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some handy Linq extension methods to get the job done. `SelectMany` will flatten the lists and select all the items, and `Distinct` will remove any duplicates:

```
List<string> mergedLists = ListsToMerge.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Without LINQ

```
List<string> MergedList = new List<string>();
foreach(List<string> ls in ListsToMerge)
{
    foreach(string s in ls)
    {
       if(!MergedList.Contains(s))
       {
           MergedList.Add(s)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be MergedList is always null.

Comment: @fliedonion what do you mean?

Comment: I think you did not initialize MergedList. so `if(!MergedList.Contains(s))` raises null reference exception.